# How do I stop "Missing AWS Lambda trace data for X-Ray" errors that happen after an INIT_START event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

The lambda's configs:

```
Logs and metrics (default): enabled
Active tracing: enabled
Enhanced monitoring: enabled
```

The role's permissions for xray:

```
"xray:PutTraceSegments",
"xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
"xray:GetSamplingRules",
"xray:GetSamplingTargets",
"xray:GetSamplingStatisticSummaries"
```

Whenever the lambda hits `INIT_START`:

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:16.v13   Runtime Version 
ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2::runtime:redacted
```

I get an error in the logs:

```
undefined   ERROR   Error: Missing AWS Lambda trace data for X-Ray. 
Ensure Active Tracing is enabled and no subsegments are created outside the function handler.
```

Active tracing is enabled  so I don't think that's the issue. There is no use of `AWSXRay.getSegment`. There are no other errors related to XRay in the logs, just the one after INIT_START.

What could be causing this? How do I track it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting this out with AWS support there are two possible fixes:

1. Find out all the places in your code where tracing is happening and confirm that it's being implemented properly -- fix if possible
2. Set an env var `AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING` with `IGNORE_ERROR` value in your code

In my case the first one was in a codebase that was a bit out of my control and we weren't very concerned about the error so I used the env var to just ignore the error in my lambda.

Answer (score 0):

`Ensure Active Tracing is enabled and no subsegments are created outside the function handler.`

Xray does not support create subsegment outside of user's Lambda function. If user calls API beginSubsegment() NOT in Lambda function, every time Lambda initializes a new sandbox will get this error.

Comment: "Active tracing is enabled so I don't think that's the issue. There is no use of AWSXRay.getSegment" -- I don't see any use of any code involving segments anywhere in our code.

Comment: If you instrument your AWS SDK clients with AWSXRay.captureAWSv3Client, you will see this if you make calls to an AWS service during your initialization code.  This qualifies as creating a subsegment outside of the function handler.